# DateTimeOffset::Now continues where it left off after the process was suspended and resumed

Tags: c#, powershell, time

I have a PowerShell script that returns the memory usage of a particular PID, example output:

```
...
1506277002989 (*nix TS) - Pid:11640 - 263.47 M
1506277003010 (*nix TS) - Pid:11640 - 263.47 M
1506277003033 (*nix TS) - Pid:11640 - 263.47 M
... // output continues
```

If I suspend the PowerShell process which monitors the PID for two seconds and then continue it again, the timestamp becomes incorrect, shifted to the past.

In my PowerShell script I use this function to sample time:

```bsh
while (1) {
    $date = [DateTimeOffset]::Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
    Write-Host -NoNewline "$date (*nix TS) - "
    ... # script continues
```

This is the code I use to suspend and resume the process:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProcessSuspendAndCtd
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int pid = Int32.Parse(args[0]);
            SuspendProcess(pid);
            Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
            ResumeProcess(pid);
        }

        [Flags]
        private enum ThreadAccess : int
        {
            TERMINATE = (0x0001),
            SUSPEND_RESUME = (0x0002),
            GET_CONTEXT = (0x0008),
            SET_CONTEXT = (0x0010),
            SET_INFORMATION = (0x0020),
            QUERY_INFORMATION = (0x0040),
            SET_THREAD_TOKEN = (0x0080),
            IMPERSONATE = (0x0100),
            DIRECT_IMPERSONATION = (0x0200)
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr OpenThread(ThreadAccess dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint dwThreadId);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern uint SuspendThread(IntPtr hThread);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern int ResumeThread(IntPtr hThread);
        [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);


        internal static void SuspendProcess(int pid)
        {
            var process = Process.GetProcessById(pid);

            if (process.ProcessName == string.Empty)
                return;

            foreach (ProcessThread pT in process.Threads)
            {
                IntPtr pOpenThread = OpenThread(ThreadAccess.SUSPEND_RESUME, false, (uint)pT.Id);

                if (pOpenThread == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                SuspendThread(pOpenThread);

                CloseHandle(pOpenThread);
            }
        }

        internal static void ResumeProcess(int pid)
        {
            var process = Process.GetProcessById(pid);

            if (process.ProcessName == string.Empty)
                return;

            foreach (ProcessThread pT in process.Threads)
            {
                IntPtr pOpenThread = OpenThread(ThreadAccess.SUSPEND_RESUME, false, (uint)pT.Id);

                if (pOpenThread == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var suspendCount = 0;
                do
                {
                    suspendCount = ResumeThread(pOpenThread);
                } while (suspendCount > 0);

                CloseHandle(pOpenThread);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:** why does the clock become desynchronized if I call the function time and time again? Is it because it synchronizes with the system time only during initialization? How should I solve it in the most general way?

Comment: Please post the suspend/resume code in the question, nobody wants to click shady external links

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17431336

Comment: @timmyRS approved

Comment: The suspension code is secondary to the question, hence it is added as an external link. And as for the shadiness - it can be easilly tested by removing the query part and going to the FQD to verify the site (or using services for that).

Comment: What process are you suspending and resuming? The process you are monitoring? The Powershell process? Please be clear.

Comment: Clarified - it is the powershell process that monitors the PID.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this - when I suspend the process for 5 seconds (using your sample suspend/resume application), the next printed timestamp is at least 6000+, can you show us the rest of the code? Maybe include some details about the OS and versions of powershell and .NET you're using

Comment: `DateTimeOffset.Now` just delegates to `DateTime.Now`, which, on Windows (which this is, judging from the P/Invoke calls) calls `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`, so any problem there should be directly attributable to the OS. Note that suspending/resuming a process by suspending all its threads is not something you can expect to work reliably in general, regardless of why you're doing it.